# google-tv emulator appears to start up, but then does nothing

Tags: android, ubuntu-11.04, google-tv

i recently re-partitioned my windows 7 laptop to also run unbuntu 11.04 so that i could try out the Google TV add-on for Android. i followed the requirements spec'd out for getting the SDK emulator to run a Google TV avd, however the emulator still doesn't work. when i load the new avd, a window with the skin appears ... then nothing else.

launching the avd from the terminal with:

*emulator @ -scale .5 -verbose*

gives back the line "emulator: KVM mode auto-enabled!"
and ends with some info about the display surface and pixel formats. i see no errors or warnings.

if i launch the avd with kvm disabled:

*emulator @ -scale .5 -verbose -qemu -disable-kvm*

the emulator and skin load, however the emulator is crazy slow (unusable slow) and the graphics are significantly degraded, like low-res CGA ... but the google tv logo does appear and i do get to a Home screen. (note, the trace ends at the same place with info about the display surface)

also...when running the AVD with KVM *adb devices* shows the emulator as offline and i'm unable to connect *adb logcat*. when running the AVD with *-disable-kvm* i can hook up to the emulator with logcat no problem. (perhaps this makes sense tho?)

my current specs:

- HP Pav dv6000
- AMD Turion 64 X2 Mobile TL-60 (with KVM enabled via BIOS)
- nVidia GeForce 7150M
- Unbuntu 11.04
- KVM (followed the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)
- KVM permissions (as spec'd here: http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator.html#KVM)
- Android SDK (latest as of this writing)

hoping someone can help me debug this, tx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop or change the `-scale .5` to fix the "CGA" issue. That's [a known issue with the Linux emulator](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18299). Either go < 0.5 or >= 1.0 on the scale factor -- between 0.5 and 1.0 is the problem zone. So, try `-scale 0.49`.

With respect to the speed, yes, that's an issue, no different than with Honeycomb. I don't know if the Turion 64 X2 has the equivalent of the Core i7 Turbo Boost mode that you can enable. Drawing to the screen is handled completely by the CPU and on only one core, and larger screen sizes (tablets and TVs) is too much without a CPU with serious single-core speed.

Comment: ah ok thanks mark. on emulator's 'scale' flag ... that fixed my 'cga' issue, but only when running the emulator with kvm disabled. so performance is still below usable (eg, if i try opening the settings activity, logcat shows a lot of GCs and eventually a launch timeout. settings never loads.)

i assume, maybe incorrectly, that running the emulator in a kvm will perform much better. but with scale set to .40 (for example) yields the same results with kvm enabled. that is, the emulator window launchs with the skin, but the emulated screen stays black and logcat cannot be attached. any thoughts?

Comment: @newbyca: I haven't tried KVM yet. Ping me back in a day if I have not commented, as I was planning on experimenting with KVM later today. Also, if you have 4GB+ of system RAM, set the "Device RAM size" in your emulator to 1024, which may help some sans KVM.

Comment: @newbyca: Well, KVM is working for me. Remarkably well, too -- I didn't even have to disable the VirtualBox driver like the docs said I would. I am not certain what advice to give you.

Comment: thanks again for the help and pointing out the emulator bug report. the google tv emulator documentation did mention possible issues with AMD systems (tho nothing specific) so i'm guessing my root issue falls there.

i actually ended up trying again on one of my Intel systems and got it working. and wow, yes the emulator is so much better with KVM. 

for anyone interested, i actually wrote up a walk-thru on [loading the google tv emulator from a usb flash drive](http://cubiclepi.com/2011/09/running-r1-google-tv-emulator-on-a-windows-pc-sorta/).

Comment: @newbyca: That's a very handy post. I was considering doing the same experiment, glad to see it works.